# How to get negative return codes from powershell to ansible

Tags: windows, powershell, error-handling, ansible

Iam trying to return a negative return code from a PowerShell script (.ps1) to Ansible. However the -ve codes that the  script returns get converted into a large +ve integer for some reason. The script works fine if the return codes are +ve integers.

BTW The large +ve integer can be calculated like so:

4294967197 = 4294967296-99 (where -99 is the return code from PowerShell and 4294967296 = 4 * 1024**3 )

Appreciate any help. Thanks!

**Details:**

- ansible version: 2.9.6
- PSVersion  : 5.1.14393.3383
- Windows : Server 2016 version 1607 (OS Build 14393.3383)
- python : 2.7.5

Also if i try this from the Windows Command Prompt it works !:

```
C:\> powershell -NoProfile %USERPROFILE%\Documents\ps_file_create.ps1

C:\> echo %errorlevel%
-99
```

This is what I have tried .. everything commented in the ansible/ps scripts below is what i have tried( I have also tried win_shell and get same results )

PowerShell Script (ps_file_create.ps1 ):

```
$return_code = -99  ## createfile $FileName
#return $return_code
#exit $return_code
$host.SetShouldExit($return_code)
exit
```

Ansible code:

```
  - name: Execute the PowerShell Script that returns a -ve return code 
    #win_command: powershell -NonInteractive -NoProfile Invoke-Expression -Command ".\ps_file_create.ps1" 
    #win_command: powershell -NonInteractive -NoProfile .\ps_file_create.ps1
    #win_command: powershell -NonInteractive -NoProfile -file ".\ps_file_create.ps1" 
    #win_command: powershell -NonInteractive -NoProfile -Command ".\ps_file_create.ps1" 
    win_command: powershell .\ps_file_create.ps1 
    args:
      chdir: '%USERPROFILE%\Documents'
    register: win_ps_out   
    ignore_errors: true       

  - name: Print Results of tasks
    debug:
      msg: 
        - "Powershell Out put: {{ win_ps_out  | to_nice_json}}"
```

Output:

```
TASK [Print Results of tasks]*****************************************************************
    ok: [myserver.xyz.abc.com] =>
      msg:
      - |-
        Powershell Out put: {
            "changed": true,
            "cmd": "powershell .\\ps_file_create.ps1",
            "delta": "0:00:00.532040",
            "end": "2020-04-20 01:32:30.515580",
            "failed": true,
            "msg": "non-zero return code",
            "rc": 4294967197,  ##  Expected -99 ##
            "start": "2020-04-20 01:32:29.983539",
            "stderr": "",
            "stderr_lines": [],
            "stdout": "",
            "stdout_lines": []
        }
```

Comment: As far as I understand Ansible module start PowerShell. Is Ansible Module 32 or 64 bit exe ?

Comment: confirmed that we have 64 bit binaries both ansible and python. Further more I also tried casting the returncode as a string but get the same rersult. But thx for your time  @JPBlanc

Answer (score 1):

What happened if in your PowerShell script you just try :

```
exit -99
```

in spite of using `$host.SetShouldExit($return_code)`

When using `cmd.exe`, I try  it the result seems to be Ok :

```
c:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command "exit -99"
echo %errorlevel%
-99
```

In fact your code gives the same result :

```
c:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command "$host.SetShouldExit(-99)"
echo %errorlevel%
-99
```

You should have a look on Ansible side where it seems to be interpreted as a 64 bits, on PowerShell side it'a a 32 bits.

Comment: I have tried this ( 3rd line in my PS script) when I do exit -99 in my ps script I get a rc of 1 in ansible instead of -99. Also it behaves same in Windows Command prompt when I check %errorlevel%  I get a rc of 1 instead of -99. Very strange behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, here is a workaround. You can define conditional tasks or a conditional output like this:

```
---
- hosts: windows
  tasks:
  - name: Execute the PowerShell Script that returns a -ve return code
    win_command: powershell .\ps_file_create.ps1 
    args:
      chdir: '%USERPROFILE%\Documents'
    register: win_ps_out   
    ignore_errors: true       

  - name: Conditional task for positive rc
    debug:
      msg: "PowerShell rc: {{ win_ps_out.rc }}"
    when: win_ps_out.rc <= 2147483647

  - name: Conditional task for negative rc
    debug:
      msg: "PowerShell rc: {{ win_ps_out.rc - 4294967296 }}"
    when: win_ps_out.rc > 2147483647

  - name: Conditional output
    debug:
      msg: "PowerShell rc: {% if win_ps_out.rc > 2147483647 %}{{ win_ps_out.rc - 4294967296 }}{% else %}{{ win_ps_out.rc }}{% endif %}"
```

Output for a return code of 42:

```
TASK [Conditional task for positive rc] ****************************************
ok: [192.168.0.200] => {
    "msg": "PowerShell rc: 42"
}

TASK [Conditional task for negative rc] ****************************************
skipping: [192.168.0.200]

TASK [Conditional output] ******************************************************
ok: [192.168.0.200] => {
    "msg": "PowerShell rc: 42"
}
```

And for a return code of -99:

```
TASK [Conditional task for positive rc] ****************************************
skipping: [192.168.0.200]

TASK [Conditional task for negative rc] ****************************************
ok: [192.168.0.200] => {
    "msg": "PowerShell rc: -99"
}

TASK [Conditional output] ******************************************************
ok: [192.168.0.200] => {
    "msg": "PowerShell rc: -99"
}
```

---

**Background**

The return code shown in the question is "correct". The binary representation of a negative integer value is  commonly calculated by the [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) method. E. g., the binary representation of -99 (using 32 bits) is:

```
‭1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1001 1101‬
```

But from reading these bits, you don't know if they represent a negative number in two's complement form or just a large positive number. You can interpret these bits either as the small negative number -99 or as the large positive number ‭4.294.967.197‬, which is what you are seeing in your output.

PowerShell returns exactly those 4 bytes shown above. You can confirm that PowerShell uses 32-bit exit codes even on a 64-bit operating system:

```bsh
PS C:\> [Environment]::Is64BitProcess -and [Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem
True
PS C:\> $process = Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "exit 0xffffffff" -Wait -PassThru
PS C:\> $process.ExitCode
-1
PS C:\> $process = Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "exit 0x1ffffffff" -Wait -PassThru
PS C:\> $process.ExitCode
0
PS C:\> $process.ExitCode.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Int32                                    System.ValueType
```

You can see that the exit code is of type `Int32` and also that PowerShell has an exit code of `0` if the "real" exit code exceeds the range of `Int32`.

So PowerShell does nothing wrong here. It is up to the user who evaluates those 4 bytes to interpret them as a signed or an unsigned integer. So it is up to ansible.

As far as I know, you don't have many possibilities to influence ansible on how to capture results from a task. You can only use filters and algorithms to process the results.

There is no such thing as type casting as far as I know (`{{ win_ps_out.rc | int }}` is actually a jinja2 filter, not a cast). And ansible does not seem to care about variable sizes. E. g., ansible is not aware of `int32` or `int64`. Just `int`, and that can be very large numbers, even larger than `int64` could hold. So what ansible does, is taking the 4 bytes from PowerShell and storing them as an integer with additional - I don't know how many - leading zeros. This would be an example for 64 bits:

```
‭0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1001 1101‬
```

Now, this number cannot be interpreted as a negative number in two's complement form, because the most significant bit is set to `0`. It can only be interpreted as 4.294.967.197, what happens in your case.

It is now up to you to handle this value. On the top of my answer I present two workarounds to process the returned value and treat it as a signed integer with a size of 32 bits.

Comment: that solution is implied in my question. The reason I did not use that to get around the problem is that it requires me to assume that any rc > 2147483647 is a negative number which may or may not be true. However since there isnt any other option I will accept this. Thanks for your valuable time   !

Comment: @objectNotFound For now, you can rely on the fact, that Windows will return a 32-bit value, even on a 64-bit OS. It is a general habit of Windows, not only of PowerShell. You can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status#Windows) (see also the references).